# How do I get my caesar cipher to read spaces in my menu option

Tags: java

I have a menu option in my program that allows for a user to change his message (case 3:) but this option keeps printing an error. I have sc.nextLine(); inputted right now which I thought would work but errors just keep popping up. I took out the Line and made it just sc.next(); which allows it to print but only if there are no spaces. Enter a space and an error will pop up. Please look at case 3:

package caesarCipher;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CaeserCipher {
     public static String encrypt(String Salad, int CipherKeyLength) 
{
        String EncryptedMessage = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Salad.length(); i++) {

            int c = Salad.charAt(i); 
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                c = c + (CipherKeyLength % 26); 
                if (c > 'Z') 
                    c = c - 26; 

            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                 c = c + (CipherKeyLength % 26);
                if (c > 'z')
                    c = c - 26;
            }
            EncryptedMessage = EncryptedMessage + (char) c;
         }
         return EncryptedMessage;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String Salad, int CipherKeyLength) {
        String DecryptedMessage = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Salad.length(); i++) {
            int c = Salad.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                c = c - (CipherKeyLength % 26);
                if (c < 'A')
                    c = c + 26;
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                c = c - (CipherKeyLength % 26);
                if (c < 'a')
                    c = c + 26;
            }
            DecryptedMessage = DecryptedMessage + (char) c;
        }
       return DecryptedMessage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Salad;
        int CipherKeyLength;
        int Menu;

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Message You Wish To 
 Encrypt Or Decrypt:");
        Salad = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nPlease Enter Your Encryption Key The 
Number of Places You Want It To Shift (1-25): ");
        CipherKeyLength = sc.nextInt();

        do {

            System.out.println(
                    "\n--------------MENU--------------\n\n1 - ALLOWS 
YOU TO ENCRYPT YOUR MESSAGE\n2 - ALLOWS YOU TO DECRYPT YOUR 
MESSAGE\n3 - ALLOWS YOU TO CHANGE YOUR ORIGINAL MESSAGE OR JUST START 
A NEW ONE ALTOGETHER\n4 - ALLOWS YOU TO CHANGE YOUR ENCRYPTION KEY\n5 
- EXIT PROGRAM\n\n--PLEASE MAKE A SELECTION BY CHOOSING ONE OF THE 
ABOVE NUMBER OPTIONS--");

            Menu = sc.nextInt();

            switch (Menu) {
            case 1:

                System.out.println("\nYour Encrypted Message 
Reads...\n\n" + encrypt(Salad, CipherKeyLength));
                break;
            case 2:

                System.out.println("Your Decrypted Message 
Reads...\n\n"
                        + decrypt(encrypt(Salad, CipherKeyLength), 
CipherKeyLength));
                break;
            case 3:
                 System.out.println("Please Enter The Message You 
  Wish To Encrypt Or Decrypt:");
                Salad = sc.nextLine();
                 System.out.println(
                         "\nPlease Enter Your Encryption Key The 
 Number of Places You Want It To Shift (1-25): ");
                CipherKeyLength = sc.nextInt();

                break;
           case 4:
                System.out.println(
                        "\nPlease Enter Your Encryption Key The 
Number of Places You Want It To Shift (1-25): ");
               CipherKeyLength = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.err.println(Menu + " Is Not A Valid Option. 
Please Try Again.");
            }

        } while (Menu != 5);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution may be helpful.

This solves your **title** issue: Reading spaces from input

```
Reader r = new StringReader(Salad);
read(r);
...
private static void read(Reader r) throws IOException {
    int readChar;
    while ((readChar = r.read()) != -1) {
        char c = (char) readChar;
        if (c == ' '){
            //if character is a space, do something
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the `case 3` of your `switch`, it seems that previously, `CipherKeyLength = sc.nextInt();` left a newline in the input. Thus, that newline is consumed by the **first** `sc.nextLine()` and skips the first input. To solve this, add `sc.nextLine();` before `Salad = sc.nextLine();`:

```
sc.nextLine(); 
Salad = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: It worked, I realize it was skipping the first input but could you please explain why sc.nextLine(); above Salad solved the problem. Why do I need it when it's stated already.

Comment: After typing `CipherKeyLength` value, the cursor remains on the **same** line as the input;  but after typing `Salad` value, which is found on the **next** line, the cursor **cannot** read that value and will read the **empty** space after `CipherKeyLength` value. Thus, an additional `sc.nextLine()` will make the cursor go to the **next** line to read the `Salad` value.